# Error when running composer install: php_intl missing

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, php-extension

I'm trying to run composer install to update an apps composer dependencies.

when I run: composer install

I get the error:

```
 Could not delete /var/www/html/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/DefinitionCache/Serializer/HTML/4.11.0,42d2529d2d2aa4f137a4d6d6292a92e3ee82eb86,1.ser: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_intl (/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_intl.so (/usr/  
  lib64/php/modules/php_intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))
```

Checking php info, I seem to have intl:

```
php -i

intl

Internationalization support => enabled
version => 1.1.0
ICU version => 50.2
ICU Data version => 50.2
ICU TZData version => 2018e
ICU Unicode version => 6.2
```

Checking loded ini files:

```
php -i | grep ini
```

Shows I should check out  /etc/php.ini and  /etc/php.d/20-intl.ini, both of which have:

```
; Enable intl extension module
extension=intl
```

Looking in /usr/lib64/php/modules/ I can see intl.so

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  472024 May  5 18:10 intl.so
```

Checking I have really installed this extension, I check

```
sudo yum list installed | grep php
mariadb.x86_64                  3:10.2.10-2.amzn2.0.3         @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
mariadb-common.x86_64           3:10.2.10-2.amzn2.0.3         @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
mariadb-config.x86_64           3:10.2.10-2.amzn2.0.3         @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
mariadb-libs.x86_64             3:10.2.10-2.amzn2.0.3         @amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
php-cli.x86_64                  7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-common.x86_64               7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-fpm.x86_64                  7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-gd.x86_64                   7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-intl.x86_64                 7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-json.x86_64                 7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-mbstring.x86_64             7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-mysqlnd.x86_64              7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-pdo.x86_64                  7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
php-xml.x86_64                  7.2.30-1.amzn2                @amzn2extra-php7.2
```

How can I resolve this error and get composer install/update to work?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of all other extensions? Are they also set to root/root?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same permissions.